# Use of undeclared type UITextfield

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am getting the following error:

> Use of undeclared type `UITextfield`

on `@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextfield!`

I have imported UIKit framework at the top

Comment: the only text field from the apple SDK i know was `UITextField `

Comment: Use UITextField instead of UITextfield

Comment: Simple typo mistake closing !!

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use a type that doesn't exist. Try changing `UITextfield` to `UITextField`, and if that doesn't work right away go to `Project > Clean`, which will simply refresh your project.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue. In my case, I had simply forgotten to import UIKit at the top of my source file:

```
import UIKit
```